# Will constant defined in Parsetree will override the constant defined in Asttypes?

Tags: compiler-construction, ocaml

I found both Asttypes and Parsetree both defined type constant:

Parsetree:

```
type constant = 
| Pconst_integer of string * char option 
| Pconst_char of char 
| Pconst_string of string * string option 
| Pconst_float of string * char option
```

Asttypes:

```
type constant = 
| Const_int of int 
| Const_char of char 
| Const_string of string * string option 
| Const_float of string 
| Const_int32 of int32 
| Const_int64 of int64 
| Const_nativeint of nativeint
```

and Parsetree will open module Asttypes in ocaml / parsing / parsetree.mli :

```
open Asttypes
```

so Will constant defined in Parsetree will override the constant defined in Asttypes?

I have this test program:

```
let ()=
 let filename = "/home/wk/prog/LocationTest/c.ml" in
 Location.input_name := filename ;
 let readhandle = open_in filename in
 let buf = Lexing.from_channel readhandle in
 Location.init buf filename ;
 let ast = Parse.implementation buf in
 Printf.printf "%d" buf.lex_buffer_len;
 let a=(List.nth ast 0).pstr_desc in
 match a with
 |Pstr_eval (x,y)->
  match x.pexp_desc with
  |Pexp_constant z->
    match z with 
    |Pconst_integer (x,y)->
     Printf.printf "%d" x;
```

c.ml only have one line,defined a number

this program can't work,the compiler tell me it need type Asttypes.constant

if I change the last two line to :

```
|Const_int q->
   Printf.printf "%d" q;
```

It works fine,and display the number in c.ml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not override it, but it will shadow it. So both types are still known to the compiler and still exist, however, when you use an unqualified `constant` it will refer to the type constructor defined in the last opened module. Basically, the `open` statement just enables unqualified access. You can still access values and types from other modules, provided that you qualify their names with module names, e.g., `Asttypes.constant`, `Parsetree.constant`. The same is true with constructors, e.g., `Asttypes.Const_int`, values, modules, classes, and other items defined in the module.